# How to make Bot Framework channels pick up changed Bot

Tags: botframework, channel

I have developed a small bot using Microsoft Bot Framework. I have deployed it to Azure as an App Service and hooked numerous channels to it. DirectLine, Skype, Facebook and Telegram. Everything worked as expected. I then updated my code to a new distinctly different dialog and republished to Azure from Visual Studio. Now I am seeing strange behavior. My DirectLine channel, my embedded WebChat and the emulator picked up the new bot. My Facebook channel, Skype channel and Telegram channel are still playing the old bot. Any hints what might be causing this? Is Microsoft hosting replicas of my bot? I have restarted everything and even deleted and recreated the App Service, but to no avail.

Tilo

Answer (score 0):

You have probably started conversations on the channels where you still have the old version. The BotState is preserved even after code modification.

> If you want to manually reset the conversation's dialog stack and state during development of your bot, you can use the `/deleteprofile` command to delete state data. Make sure to include the leading space in this command, to prevent the channel from interpreting it.
>
> After your bot has been deployed to production, you can version your bot data so that if you bump the version, the associated state data is cleared. With the Bot Builder SDK for Node.js, this can be accomplished using middleware and with the Bot Builder SDK for .NET, this can be accomplished using an `IPostToBot` implementation.

More details on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/troubleshoot-general-problems?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#how-do-i-version-the-bot-data-stored-through-the-state-api)

Comment: I am not sure if what you are describing was my issue. My two bots had totally different codes and dialogs. So I think I was really seeing different code executing on channels which were pointing to the same bot. The issue disappeared in the meantime. And thanks for the secret command, I learned something 